# Precomputing simple values for a function in Go

Tags: go, ocaml

I just started using Go for a simple web programming project, but I can't quite figure out how to accomplish simple pre-computation local to a single function. This is something I do quite frequently in OCaml, e.g.:

```
(* maybe render_page is a handler function for an HTTP server or something *)
let render_page =
  (* let's say that Template.prepare takes a template string and returns its compiled representation *)
  let templ = Template.prepare "user: {{.}}, group: {{.}}" in
  (* return an anonymous function *)
  fun user group ->
    templ [user; group]
```

For those unfamiliar with OCaml, what's happening above is I'm binding the name `render_page` to a function that takes two parameters and presumably returns a web page, but internally I'm first creating a local binding to `templ` (this binding is only visible within the definition of `render_page`, and the computation only happens once) and then using that binding within an anonymous function, which is the actual value bound to `render_page`. So when you call `render_page`, `templ` isn't recompiled every time: it's just fetched from the closure environment.

Is there a common pattern for accomplishing something like this in Go? I'd like to avoid global variables as much as possible. I'm aware that "global" variables may be confined to a package's name space, which is what I'm currently doing, but I'd like to restrict the visibility of these precomputed expressions to just the functions in which they're needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Go does not have function-local static variables. If you want to share a mutable value between executions of a function, it must be a global variable. You can use function-local constants for immutable values, but constants are limited to the built-in types.

Comment: You could also make the variable a member of a struct, and convert the function to a method on that struct, depending on your use case. You would still need to ensure the same instance of the struct was re-used. Personally I would just use a global though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with Ocaml so not 100% sure if this Go example is what you are looking for, but you can define a function in Go which can pre-calculate some stuff and then return an anonymous function that internally uses the pre-calculated values.

For example, if you do this:

```
func matcher(pattern string) func(string) bool {
    regExp := regexp.MustCompile(pattern)
    return func(s string) bool {
        return regExp.MatchString(s)
    }
}
```

And then create one of these functions by doing:

```
myMatcher := matcher("123")
```

You can then call `myMatcher("something")` multiple times, and the regexp expression will not be compiled each time since it was already compiled when calling the `matcher` function.

Here's a working Go playground with this:

https://play.golang.org/p/m3vBrYn4Dg

Comment: You can also bind the resulting closure to a global variable, and then you can use it like other functions (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think a closure (similar to what @eugenioy already answered with) is the closest you are going to get.

```
func main() {
    userGroupTemplate := renderPage()
    fmt.Println(userGroupTemplate("sberry", "StackOverflow"))
    fmt.Println(userGroupTemplate("user1030453", "StackOverflow"))
}

func renderPage() func(user, group string) string {
    templ := "user: %s, group: %s"
    fmt.Println("template is created")
    return func(user, group string) string {
        return fmt.Sprintf(templ, user, group)
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
template is created
user: sberry, group: StackOverflow
user: user1030453, group: StackOverflow
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers here, note that once you define a closure, you can bind it to a global variable and treat it like other functions.
Here is eugenioy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44337351/124319) slightly modified :

```
var scan = matcher("123")

func main() {
    fmt.Println(scan("456"))
    fmt.Println(scan("123"))
}
```

Here, `scan` is a global closure, which is very close to what you did in OCaml.

https://play.golang.org/p/Lc0SC53b-0